# Why doesn't the that-trace effect affect the sentence "Who that knows him doesn't love him?"?

Tags: grammar, that

In the entry [that-trace effect](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/That-trace_effect) in Glottopedia, the following sentence is shown as an ungrammatical example.

> *Who did you think **that** would win?

But, I believe that the next sentence is grammatical.

> Who **that** knows him doesn't love him?

What is the difference?

Comment: The second example is a relative clause construction with the understood relative pronoun as subject of the relative clause.  Compare it with the almost grammatical "Who who knows him doesn't love him?"  The relative pronoun is already at the beginning of the relative clause, so there is no movement, hence no trace.  (I recall that this is controversial, and that the matter is argued in **GPSG** the book.  I don't remember the details.)

Comment: "whoever", not "whomever" (subject, not object)

Comment: Who knows him that doesn't love him?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct—the first sentence is ungrammatical while the second is grammatical. The devil, as always, is in the details. Consider the description of the [*that-trace effect*](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/That-trace_effect):

> …the phenomenon that the complementizer (*that*) cannot be **followed** by a trace…

(Emphasis mine.)

In the first example, the “that” *follows* the trace. The sentence, prior to [wh-movement](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Wh-movement), would be the following:

> Did you think that she would win?

Therefore, the *trace* is at the position of the original “she,” which comes directly after the complementizer. Contrast this with the same transformation applied to the second sentence:

> He that knows him doesn't love him?

In this example, the “he” *precedes* the “that,” so the *that*-t effect does not apply.